# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

I'm an Android developer, and i only do some side-gig iOS programming, so please forgive me for being quite a beginner.

I'm encountering a nasty issue i can't seem to solve.

When in the "homepage" of the app, there's a view the user can tap to get to another view controller. Problem is, the new view controller seems to make the app crash just after viewWillAppear().

From the "homepage":

```
let tap_datiutente = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.func_tap_datiutente(_:)))
    view_datiutente.addGestureRecognizer(tap_datiutente)

[...]

@objc func func_tap_datiutente (_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if pref_login?.integer(forKey: Costanti.sp_stato_login) == Costanti.sp_int_visitatore {
        // Just an alert for non-registered users, who can't access this view //
        Operatore.MostraAlert(viewController: self, titolo: "Attenzione", testo: "Questa funzione è riservata agli utenti già registrati.")
    } else {
        // This is the action performed to reach the view controller //
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seg_home_profilo", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class DatiUtente: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroll_view: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var view_1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_nome_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_cognome_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_indirizzo_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_numciv_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_cap_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_comune_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_provincia_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_cod_fisc_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_piva_fatt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var constr_1: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var view_2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_nome_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_cognome_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_indirizzo_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_cap_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_comune_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_provincia_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_numciv_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_codfisc_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_numcell_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf_email_allievo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var view_privacy_1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var switch_privacy_1: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var view_privacy_2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var switch_privacy_2: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var constr_2: NSLayoutConstraint!


    /* METODI DI OVERRIDE */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewDidLoad")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pref_login = UserDefaults(suiteName: Costanti.SP_LOGIN)

        tf_nome_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "nomefatt")
        tf_cognome_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "cognomefatt")
        tf_indirizzo_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "indirfatt")
        tf_numciv_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "numcivfatt")
        tf_cap_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "capfatt")
        tf_comune_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "comunefatt")
        tf_provincia_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "provfatt")
        tf_cod_fisc_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "codfiscfatt")
        tf_piva_fatt.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "pivafatt")
        tf_nome_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "nome")
        tf_cognome_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "cognome")
        tf_indirizzo_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "indirizzo")
        tf_numciv_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "numciv")
        tf_cap_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "cap")
        tf_comune_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "comune")
        tf_provincia_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "prov")
        tf_codfisc_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "codfisc")
        tf_numcell_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "cell")
        tf_email_allievo.text = pref_login?.string(forKey: "email")

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        let tap_privacy_1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.privacy(_:)))
        view_privacy_1.addGestureRecognizer(tap_privacy_1)

        let tap_privacy_2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.privacypolicy(_:)))
        view_privacy_2.addGestureRecognizer(tap_privacy_2)

        scroll_view.delaysContentTouches = false

        print("viewDidLoad finished")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("viewWillAppear")
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("viewWillAppear finished")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidAppear")
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        Mostra_View_1()
        print("viewDidAppear finished")
    }
}

[...]

private func Mostra_View_1() {
    view_1.isHidden = false
    view_2.isHidden = true
    HideKeyboard()
    constr_1.constant = 25
    constr_1.isActive = true
    constr_2.isActive = false
    scroll_view.scrollToTop()
}

private func Mostra_View_2() {
    view_2.isHidden = false
    view_1.isHidden = true
    HideKeyboard()
    constr_2.constant = 25
    constr_1.isActive = false
    constr_2.isActive = true
    scroll_view.scrollToTop()
}

private func HideKeyboard() {
    tf_nome_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_cognome_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_indirizzo_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_numciv_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_cap_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_comune_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_provincia_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_cod_fisc_fatt.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_piva_fatt.resignFirstResponder()

    tf_nome_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_cognome_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_indirizzo_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_numciv_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_cap_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_comune_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_provincia_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_codfisc_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_numcell_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
    tf_email_allievo.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I've already tried emptying the viewDidLoad function, but it's still not working.

The log simply stops at:

```
viewDidLoad
viewDidLoad finished
viewWillAppear
viewWillAppear finished
(lldb)
```

and throws this exception:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2a26849f8)
```

while pointing at

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I've already tried enabling zombies, but with no luck. The memory profiling just shows "Unknown" at the flag of the crash.

I'm really confused. Got any hint for me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As the error says, there's a bad access error.
This is all your viewController ? Are you sure you have all outlets linked to the storyboard ? 
Check if one or more outlets have more than one link: in you storyboard select your element, you can ctrl+click to see which outlets are linked to it, or you can select your element and check the right arrow tab in the inspector (the last on the right). Maybe the app can't load the view because one of this errors

Comment: Hello @Andrew21111 , all my outlets seem correctly linked. I didn't paste all my viewcontroller, but the rest of it is quite useless i believe, just some functions i call when pressing buttons and such.

Comment: *"...there's a view the user can tap to get to another view controller..."* So, tapping `privacy()` or `privacyPolicy()` is the actual issue? If so, why not include those functions? Under many *runtime* circumstances, actions not correctly wired up (same with trying to access an outlet not properly wired up) results in what you described.

Comment: @dfd The action is quite simple. It is "self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seg_home_profilo", sender: self)" . I've tried to perform another segue inside the same function, and it's working properly, so the problem shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Suspicio however, just an advice: instead of create tapGesture for each view, just use buttons without text, it's easier and prettier.
Coming back to the problem, viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear run correctly, so the problem is that the app cannot render the view, so there's a problem with some view, some link, some outlets or something else. Try to clean your project, or build another one with essentials and try to run it. Mostra_View_1 what exactly should do ?
P.S. Ho appena visto alcuni nomi di variabili in italiano!

Comment: We ciao @Andrew21111 :) I'm editing the code so you can see some more functions. But i've also tried to comment Mostra_View_1(), and still no luck.

Comment: Um, which action? You defined two actions for taps and never gave enough details to actually duplicate the issue. In fact, have you taken the time to (1) create a brand new project, (2) added "views" and "gestures", and (3) duplicate your issue? Many times that actually exposes what is really happening.

Comment: How are you showing _the new view controller_ from your _ "homepage"_? The cause of your issue may exist there.

Comment: @dfd So, i tried recreating the view (copy->paste) into a new project, and it opens. I tried then to create a new view controller in my real project, copy paste the elements without even linking them via the outlet, and it crashes when i press the button. I'm puzzled. I'll try to recreate the gesture too somehow...

Comment: @OOPer I'm editing the answer with the code in the "homepage" :)

Comment: @dfd I also recreated the gesture, and it works in the new project. Also tried, in the old project, to just perform the segue after two seconds in the homepage, and still crashes.

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information and the *real* line where the exception occurs.

Comment: @Suspicio, thanks for updating. But unfortunately, I cannot find any explicitly clear faults in your code till now. Another possibility, if any of your views included in your _new view controller_ are mal-configured, your app may crash after `viewWillAppear()`. Backup your project and try removing the views one by one and see what happens. This may be very similar to one thing what you tried, but I want it to be clarified if your app crashes or not when _new view controller_'s view is empty.

Comment: @OOPer Thank to you for answering OOPer! I found the problem thanks to your suggestion. It was a complicated view made of an horizontal stack view inside another view, divided into an image inside another view and a text inside another. Yeah, probably too much and i must have f***ed something up with the autolayout constraints :) Thank you again pal!!! You can write the answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @vadian i found the solution, anyway the breakpoint i made fired at the end of viewWillAppear :) Writing this also for future users looking for a solution.

Comment: @Suspicio, happy to hear that you solved your issue. I can only write some abstract description which may not be very useful for future readers. Please take some time to write an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was a complicated view that made the whole app crash. Should you encouter something similar, try to rebuild the view in another project, then remove one piece after the other. :) Thanks to @OOPer for the help!